# Expected occupied area of a surface covered with possibly overlapping random shapes.

Tags: probability, geometry

Given a surface with area $A$, what is the expected area of the region occupied by $k$ possibly overlapping random circles with equal radii $r$?

For example, I would like to estimate the area of the black region of [this simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD2GS.png).

If it helps, we can assume the edges of surface wraps around, so the surface is a torus. And instead of random circles, it can also be random squares.

I've tried to find an approximation by partitioning the space as a "pixel" grid and solve it as a K balls in N buckets problem. But I didn't find how to generalize it from balls to circles.

Comment: Hint: The expected area of the occupied area $C$ is the integral over $x$ in $A$ of $P(x\in C)$. What is $P(x\in C)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Making all the necessary assumptions to make this question nice, if a point has a probability $\frac{a}{A}$ of being covered by a small object of area $a$, then the probability of not being covered by it is $1-\frac{a}{A} = \frac{A-a}{A}$.

So the probability of not being covered by $k$ small independent objects is $\left(\frac{A-a}{A}\right)^k$ and the probability of being covered by at least one of them is $1- \frac{(A-a)^k}{A^k}$.

So the area covered is $A-\frac{(A-a)^k}{A^{k-1}}.$

Comment: I have a similar problem. May I know what is "A", "a", "k" in the solution? Is "A" the 2D domain where the dots are or the projected area of the dots? So are "a" and "k"?

Comment: @Alexandre Vassalotti: The last step was multiplying the probability by the area $A$

Comment: @Nelson: $A$ is the total area, $a$ is the area of each of the small objects, and $k$ is the number of small objects