# Probability distribution of the area covered by random circles

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Does anybody know of there are any asymptotic results on the probability distribution of the area covered by $n$ random circles in the unit square with radius $r=r(n)$? I believe results on the expected value exist but i haven't come across any results on variance?

Comment: Possible values the radius can take is 0 .. 1/2 ? All circles of the same radius ?

Comment: Yes all circles are of the same radius. The radius is a function of n. I was wondering if there were known results for the cases where $rn=o(1)$ or $rn=O(1)$. But i would be interested in other results too.

Comment: Only the center of the circle needs to be inside the square ? And $r(n)$ can be any function (polynomial, transcendental etc.) ?

Comment: yes $r(n)$ can even be constant.

Comment: Okay, meanwhile, I found a [old math.se question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136924/expected-occupied-area-of-a-surface-covered-with-possibly-overlapping-random-sha), see if that is of any help.

Comment: Thanks that does help! So in the thread a formula for the expected area is determined, do you think obtaining an asymptotic distribution for the area would be significantly harder?

Comment: From that formula, wouldn't that be just $A$ as $k\to \infty$ ?

Comment: does http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrami_equation 'cover' your question?

Comment: At a quick glance i'm not so sure, i think its possible the circles which are formed do not have the same radius.

Comment: @PavanSangha: we can only use statistics if the largest circle is small relative to the unit square: the area not covered by circles can be approximated by the product p1.p2 .. p_k where p_i is the area not covered by circle i (whatever its radius). Hence, we can use p1.p2 .. = (1-P_1).(1-P_2).. with (1-P_i) =~= Exp(-P_i). And those exponetials multiply nicely. That does look like a Poisson distribution, whose variance is well known. No?

Comment: @WouterM. Ok so are you suggesting a similar method to the one gar proposed in his attached thread with different radius sizes? Why is the area approximated by that product?

Comment: @PavanSangha: nothing in your question indicates that the circles should be non-overlapping. So I presume they do randomly overlap. In that case, the approximation (1-x) ~ exp(-x) can be used provided x is small compared to unity. And then a Poisson distribution follows.

Comment: @WouterM. Yes they do over lap, so you have defined the total area not covered by circle $i$ is $p_{i}$. What i'm asking why does the total area not covered by circles $C_{1},...,C_{k}$ equate to $p_{1} \times p_{2} \times ... \times p_{k}$?

Comment: @PavanSangha: probability of a point being not in C_i AND not in C_j and ... equals p_i p_j since the chances are uncorrelated because of the overlap.

Comment: Ok so i see what your saying now (i was confused at the way you phrased your answer) this is what i meant when i said is it the same as in the attached thread. So essentially given a sample point your letting $p_{i}$ be the probability that it is not covered by cirlce $C_{i}$. Hence the probability that it is not covered by any circle is $\prod_{i=1}^{k} p_{i}$ and so the probability it is covered is $\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-p_{i})$. Now you are saying this approximately poisson provided $p_{i}$ is small?